# Why was my example deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, deleted-examples

I posted [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/revisions/1964?exampleId=8582) to the Design Patterns topic in the Java tag. The example was about the static factory method pattern. I included a code example, but for the most part I included an explanation about the advantages of using the static factory pattern in Java.

While writing this, I had an audience in mind that already knows at least the basics in Java and that has at least a rough idea about how the patterns works. Thus, I focused my explanation on what happens when both are used together: The static factory pattern in Java. After all, this is the design patterns topic in the Java tag. The pattern itself should be explained in detail in the design patterns tag.

After I revisited the example later, it was edited two times. The first one added a diagram about the factory method pattern, which is different from the static factory method pattern. The second removed my code example and added one that fits the diagram. Since my explanation referred to my code, it became hard to follow when the code was replaced.

To be fair I have to add, that I mistakenly called the pattern *Factory Method* by myself, because I did not know that there was the term *Static Factory Method*. Thus, the wrong diagram was added based on the wrong title and the not matching code example was based on the diagram. But doesn't this mean that none of the editors and reviewers paid attention to what they were editing/approving?

I did some more research and found the term *Static Factory Method*. Also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929273/3888450), which contains several of the points that I included in my explanation and which has many upvotes. Thus, I thought my example is fine in general and I just need to clarify that it is actually about the *Static Factory Method* pattern and not about the *Factory Method* pattern.

Thus, [I edited the example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81196?draftId=67936) to fix the above issues and shortly described what happened in the commit message. I renamed the example from *Factory Method* to *Static Factory Method*, removed the diagram, rolled back the code example, added a statement that *Static Factory Method* is another pattern than *Factory Method* and did a few refinements to the explanation.

However, my edit was rejected because another edit was approved that removed my example completely. Now, my question is: What went wrong? I thought about several answers, but I am still not sure:

- **Did the example not match well into documentation?**

  As the tour states, documentation examples should be broad and general:

  > Examples show how to accomplish a task or solve a common problem, and they have code more often than not. Good examples are broad and generally useful, remember that Q&A exists for very specific questions!

  However, it also states that one should not explain too much, but show code that solves common tasks or problems:

  > Examples illustrate common tasks or solutions to common problems - remember "Show, Don't Tell". A good example is self-contained and succinct, and more often than not contains code. It is more important that code in examples be illustrative and focused than that it be copy/paste-able; leave out boilerplate when it distracts from the concept the example is meant to illustrate.

  Now, my explanation is certainly broad and general. However to achieve this, it contains explanation. I think it depends on the example how much explanation is actually needed to be broad and general. Is this a contradiction in the tour?
- **Did the example not match well into the topic?** Actually, I posted the example in the *Factory pattern* topic, which was later merged with the design patterns topic. However, I think either of them were a good match for the example. As explained above, I actually thought about who is going to read the example. I inferred the audience from the place where I posted my content.
- **Was the explanation or my use of the English language bad?** After all, I am not a native English speaker.
- **Did the editor that removed the example as well as the respective reviewers not do their job?** They should have seen the editing history and my suggested edit, but it is not mentioned in any of their comments. Does the system warn the reviewers that there is a conflicting edit?

Comment: The [edit which deleted your example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/83528?filter-tags=java) was fulfilling an improvement request which stated *This example does not sufficiently illustrate the point and needs to be edited to provide more details. The explanation for the code was hard to follow.*. Of course, that request just asked for clarification, so I don't know why deleting it was necessary, but that's what happened.

Comment: Documentation failing again, whodathunk?